# Adding a sum to a database - Linq

Tags: c#, linq, xaml

I have a database that has 2 tables 'Matches' and 'Teams'. When the user selected a match from the listbox I have made I take that match in and compare it to see if that match is in the database.

MY QUESTION!!!!

After this I want to add the result to the teams table (property 'points') and then remove that match from the database.

Here is how it looks so far:

```
        private void btn_Result_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MatchesTBL selected = Listbox_Matches.SelectedItem as MatchesTBL;

            if (listBox_ManagersDislay.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                var removeMatch = db.MatchesTBLs.SingleOrDefault(x => x.TeamName == selected.TeamName && x.OpponentName == selected.OpponentName); //returns a single item.

                if (removeMatch != null)
                {
                    switch (comboBox_Result.SelectedIndex)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            MessageBox.Show("You have not selected a result...");
                            break;

                        case 1:
                            // add 3 points
                            var AddWin = from Team in db.TeamTBLs
                                         where selected.TeamName == Team.TeamName
                                         select Team.Points;
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            // add 1 point
                            var AddDraw = from Team in db.TeamTBLs
                                          where selected.TeamName == Team.TeamName
                                          select Team.Points;
                            break;
                    }

                    db.MatchesTBLs.Remove(removeMatch);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

                // Repeat the on window loaded method to refresh the grids
                Window_Loaded(sender, e);

            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a match from the table");
            }
        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error has occured....");
        }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: After this I want to add the result to the teams table (property 'points') and then remove that match from the database.

Comment: And what difficulty are you having while attempting to do that?

Comment: I dont know how to access the TeamTBL.Points and add the points to that table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have change Code

```
case 1:
                    // add 3 points
                    var AddWin = (from Team in db.TeamTBLs
                                 where selected.TeamName == Team.TeamName
                                 select Team ).FirstOrDefault();                                         
                        AddWin.Points=AddWin.Points+3;
                        db.Entry(AddWin).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;     

                    break;

 case 2:
                    // add 1 point
                    var AddDraw = from Team in db.TeamTBLs
                                  where selected.TeamName == Team.TeamName
                                  select Team ).FirstOrDefault();
                    AddDraw.Points=AddWin.Points+1;
                     db.Entry(AddDraw).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;   
                    break;
```

Comment: I used a different method for my assesment but I have tested what you suggested and it worked well, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

try Code

```
 private void btn_Result_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MatchesTBL selected = Listbox_Matches.SelectedItem as MatchesTBL;

        if (listBox_ManagersDislay.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            var removeMatch = db.MatchesTBLs.SingleOrDefault(x => x.TeamName == selected.TeamName && x.OpponentName == selected.OpponentName); //returns a single item.

            if (removeMatch != null)
            {
                switch (comboBox_Result.SelectedIndex)
                {
                    case 0:
                        MessageBox.Show("You have not selected a result...");
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        // add 3 points
                        var AddWin = (from Team in db.TeamTBLs
                                     where selected.TeamName == Team.TeamName
                                     select Team ).FirstOrDefault();                                         
                            AddWin.Points=AddWin.Points+3;
                            db.Entry(AddWin).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;     
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        // add 1 point
                        var AddDraw = from Team in db.TeamTBLs
                                      where selected.TeamName == Team.TeamName
                                      select Team ).FirstOrDefault();
                        AddDraw.Points=AddWin.Points+1;
                         db.Entry(AddDraw).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;   
                        break;
                }

                db.MatchesTBLs.Remove(removeMatch);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            // Repeat the on window loaded method to refresh the grids
            Window_Loaded(sender, e);

        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a match from the table");
        }
    }

    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error has occured....");
    }
}
```

Comment: A code-only answer isn't a good answer. How does this answer the question? What is different from the original?

Comment: This question  every match Completed Result  Update Team Points  and remove matches  review code for case 1 and case 2

Comment: Fix your answer. Remove unnecessary code, post what you added and explain what it does. Comments aren't answers. You can't force people to read the entire source just to find out what changed

Comment: Besides - you do realize the two cases are identical? Typing the same query twice isn't a good idea, even if the OP did so. Selecting an entire Team when you only want the points isn't nice either